# Can there be a confirmation of disappeared transaction?

Tags: transactions, confirmations

When confirming that a transaction happened, I can simply check if the transaction is 12 or more blocks deep. Can a same approach be applied to confirming disappeared transaction?

With my research, looking for confirmed transactions with higher nonce while the original transaction being gone, proves it.

But I need a simpler approach. Does waiting for 12 blocks right after my transaction getting removed from pending pool, verify a disappeared transaction?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Interesting question/way of thinking! The yellow paper states that the nonce must be equal to the number of sent transactions. It must increment by one after each transaction, so you can't actually have a skipped nonce. See also https://myetherwallet.groovehq.com/knowledge_base/topics/what-is-nonce